# Can't run demo android project from github

Tags: android, github, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have recently started android development and am in a part where I would like to add some features I have found on github. I have never imported a project into android studio and am having problems. I have downloaded the zip file from https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage . I have extracted it and and opened up the project inside of android studio:

[image]

Then this is the screen I get when I open the project.From the screen I  want to run the 'sample' by clicking run but I get the error:

[image]

[image]

I have also tried to gradle sync the project before running the project but it did not work. Am I missing something? On Github it says the project the build is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is quite clear as to what your issue is here. Android documentaion outlines the changes to the build system [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) and more specificaly the [experimental plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) suggested in your error. Have a good read through it and follow how to migrate your build system.